# data structure for a file system--interview

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I've encountered the following interview questions online. Based on my understanding, it's asked you to design a data structure to simulate the file system. Can anyone give me some hints?

```
// addMapping("/foo/bar/x", "XController")
// addMapping("/foo/bar/z", "ZController")
// addMapping("/foo/baz", "BazController");

//getMapping("/foo/bar/x") -> ["XController"]
//getMapping("/foo/bar") -> ["XController", "ZController"]


public void addMapping(String path, String destination) {
    //candidate TODO

}

public List<String> getMapping(String path) {
    //candidate TODO  

}
```

Comment: yep a simple hint: it's not about the file-system it's about routes for websites - just look to some random MVC framework and you should find examples

Comment: and maybe if you don't know it: there is a common *convention*: if your *controller*  is named `XYZController` than it's about the route `XYZ` - this seems to be the case here too

Comment: the exercise so far seems seems easy enough .. (`StartsWith` *cough, cough*)

Comment: quick tip: at its simplest, you'd want some portion of the blocks on the disk arranged as a free-list of unused storage and in-use lists for directories and files (the simplest ways to do this are fragmentation prone, like DOS-era File Allocation Tables), then you'd want directories modeled as containers of sub-directories and files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best structure to use for this mapping is a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or even better its compressed version - a Patricia Tree(a.k.a [radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)). The idea is the following - both structures store prefixes of dictionary words. When a user queries for a given path you traverse the structure(be it a trie or a radix tree) according to the query string. After that you do any walk over the subtree under the node where you end up and print all the controllers associated with the nodes there.